# A Subfunctor of Quot-functor compatible with pullbacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, schemes, hilbert-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective irreducible algebraic curve over field $k$. For $d,r,k,m >0$ the representable Quot scheme $\mathcal {Quot}_X^{r,d}(\mathcal{O}_X(m)^k)$ is given for
any test scheme $U \to X$ by

$${\displaystyle {\mathcal {Quot}}_{X}^{r,d}(\mathcal{O}_X(m)^k)(U)=\left\{({\mathcal {F}},q):{\begin{matrix}{\mathcal {F}}\in {\text{Coh}}(X \times U)\\{\text{Supp}}({\mathcal {F}}){\text{ is proper over }}X \times U\\{\mathcal {F}}{\text{ is flat over }}X \times U\\q:(\mathcal{O}_{X\times U}(m))^k\to {\mathcal {F}}{\text{ surjective}} \\ {\text{ rank }}({\mathcal {F}})= r {\text{ and }}  {\text{ deg }}({\mathcal {F}})= d \end{matrix}}\right\}/\sim }$$

Now we want to define an subfunctor
${\mathcal {R}}_{X}^{m} \subset \mathcal {Quot}_X^{r,d}(\mathcal{O}_X(m)^k)$
by taking restriction:

$${\displaystyle {\mathcal {R}}_{X}^{m}(U)=\left\{({\mathcal {F}},q):{\begin{matrix}{\mathcal {F}}\in {\mathcal {Quot}}_{X}^{r,d}(\mathcal{O}_X(m)^k)(U) \\ {\mathcal {F}} {\text{ locally free and }} \\ H^1(X \times U, \mathcal {F}(m))=0   \end{matrix}}\right\}/\sim }$$

First obvious problem: is the thing ${\mathcal {R}}_{X}^{m}$ well defined, that is what about the compatibility with pullbacks of the last condition on $H^1$ group? i.e. I want to assure that if $U $ is an arbitrary
$k$ scheme and the quotient $\mathcal{F} \in {\mathcal {R}}_{X}^{m}(U)$
then for every $X$-morphism $f:S \to U$ the pullback $\hat{f}^*\mathcal{F}$
is an element in ${\mathcal {R}}_{X}^{m}(S)$, where $\hat{f}: X \times S \to X \times U$.

The crucial obstacle for me is to verify
$H^1(X \times S, \hat{f}^*\mathcal {F}(m))=0$.
I conjecture that here I can somehow use one of many corollaries
of the Semicontinuity Theorem (see e.g. Algebraic Geometry by R.
Hartshorne, pp 281), but don't know how it can be applied in this
situation. Any idea how to solve it? Can I make a reduction argument to reduce it to a setting where semicontinuity does the job?

Comment: It makes more sense to replace the condition $H^1 = 0$ by the ondition $R^1\pi_* = 0$, where $\pi$ is the projection to $U$. This condition is equivalent to the $H^1$ condition when $U$ is affine and it is preserved by base change.

Comment: @Sasha: Yes, you suggestion is reasonable. Then with notations from above for
$f: S \to U$ and $\hat{f}$ by flat base change formula we
obtain $R^1 (\pi_S)_* \bar{f}^* \mathcal{F}= f^* R^1(\pi_U)_* \mathcal{F}
=0$ since $\pi_U: X \times U \to U$ and $\pi_S$ are flat und thus
the semicontinuity theorem isn't neccessary here.

Comment: hhhm the only unsolved problem stays why the lecturer who gave the 
talk where this subfunctor was introduced, remarked shortly
that it is well defined by "semicontinuity".